Measuring a parameter's uncertainty with probability
On page 58 of Statistical Rethinking, Richard McElreath states that

... strict non-Bayesian inference forbids using probability to measure uncertainty about parameters’ …

I understand he’s making a point about frequentist inference relying on repetition, but isn’t a sampling distribution a probability distribution of a statistic?
What does he mean by this statement?

He's confusing two concepts by equating "uncertainty" with the subjective probability interpretation of Bayesian statistics.  Without question, most statistical inference methods provide quantitative probability statements about parameter uncertainty: it's just that the interpretation is not always the one Dr. McElreath might prefer.

It is a probability distribution of the estimator of the parameter (i.e. a statistic), which is different from a probability distribution of the parameter (the estimand). The parameter is taken as a fixed unknown in the frequentist context.

You are correct that a sampling distribution in frequentist statistics is indeed a probability distribution of a statistic such as sample mean or variance which describes the variation in the statistic that you would observe if you repeatedly sample from the population, but this distribution is not about the parameter itself such as population mean. Instead, Frequentists use tools like confidence interval and p-value which relates to the uncertainty about the parameters but not directly as a probability measure like Bayesians.

So, probability, as a method of describing uncertainty due to random variation, is used to describe the variation of a population parameter due to repeated sampling (i.e., the variation originates from the data) in the frequentist case - and, therefore, is not using probability to describe a parameter directly. Whereas, in a Bayesian case - probability is used to describe a parameter directly - because the uncertainty originates from our inability to model the parameter with certainty, there is an inherent uncertainty in our ability to fully capture it rather than from sampling. Correct?

@McGez Indeed this is another way to interpret my point, as I explicitly mentioned in my above answer that Frequentists use p-value and confidence interval to indirectly describe the uncertainty about the truly conceived parameters, their sampling probability distribution is for statistic data, not the parameters. Hope this clarifies your question.

It does, thank you.
